# sessionStorage from input

Tags: input, sessionstorage

Can someone please tell what's wrong with this code?
Even when I change `sessionStorage.setItem("item1"; document.test.value);` to a fixed value like `sessionStorage.setItem("item1"; "test");` it does nothing.
Is it a problem in the code or some browser setting?
The browser gives undefined for sessionstorage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">`
function Session()
{sessionStorage.setItem("item1"; document.test.value);}
function Show() 
{alert("Value 1 is " + sessionStorage.getItem("item1")); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="test">
<button type="button" onclick="Session()">invoer</input>
<button type="button" onclick="Show()">show</input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon where it should be a comma on this line:

{sessionStorage.setItem("item1"; document.test.value);}

Should be:

{sessionStorage.setItem("item1", document.test.value);}